# How to get rid of 401.2 in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-6

I've read a lot of documentation on this error and it all seems to point to modifying `applicationHost.config`.  I've made the modifications and mine looks like:

```
<system.webServer>
    <asp />
    <security>
        <authentication>
            <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
            <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
        </authentication>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

I've restarted the website but still get the same error.

I'm running IIS6.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need to post some more details. It is unclear what you mean by "same error". When do you get an error? Also, if using IIS6 you are configuring in the wrong place - the `<system.webServer>` section applies only to IIS 7+.

Comment: I get the error when I visit the website through the browser.